# How to upload images to AWS S3 with Ckeditor5

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to upload an image to s3 bucket from CkEditor5. My front-end is built on vue and backend is on NodeJs. The uploading of images is working as expected as i can see the image is being saved to s3 bucket correctly. However I am having a confusion whether the bucket should be public or not ?

### How CkEditor behaves to image uploading?

The ckEditor uses a simple upload adapter which uses its own built-in adapater that enables image uploading feature. When an images is dropped/copy-pasted to the ckEditor, it makes an http POST request to my backend NodeJs server and server in turns makes a call to S3 to upload that image(till this point everything is working as expected).

Now in order to embed an image inside CkEditor5, the server should respond with an URL attribute as JSON response like following so that CkEditor can fetch it and display inside editor.

```
{
  url: url-path-of-image //full path of image in s3 bucket
}
```

This is where I am confused and need some pointers.

Question 1:
Should I make it public ? If yes, then what do I do about security, making it public will give access to anybody.
If I make it accessible with key/secret, how do I do it ?

Question 2:

This one is related to question#1

If I make it public then question#2 will not be an issue.However if I am not allowed to make it public in that case how would i display the images in normal div element ? Later on I need to display the content of CkEditor inside a div, with html parsing meaning inside a v-html attribute.

Any suggestions or pointers would be much helpful. Really appreciate taking time to read through the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am looking for the solutions. I can tell that it is related to signed urls in AWS S3. You keep bucket private, upload image to S3 and generate a signed url whenever you need to display the image to user on frontend.

If you learn more into the correct implementation please let me know.

Comment: Actually I have, I wil post an answer to this.

Comment: @Saroj did you found any solution why ckeditor5 don't display image but uploading is fine

Comment: If your images are public s3 bucket then it should display the images.

Comment: How does it work with CKEditor. If I give public S3 URL, it will upload the image to S3?

Comment: @Saroj soooo.. where is the answer pal, or are you still 3 years in trying to implement? :p